# Selenium - Called method inside another class, but cannot re-use driver

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I have two different classes: "AddTeam.java" and "Login.java".

Login.java has something similar to this:

```
public class Login {
      static WebDriver driver;

public static void loginMethod () throws IOException {

       driver = new ChromeDriver(); driver.manage().window().maximize();

       HSSFWorkbook workbook;
       HSSFSheet sheet;
       HSSFCell cell;
```

And that code goes on.

AddTeam.java goes like this:

```
public class AddCompanyTeam {

    public static <IWebDriver> void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        company_teams.Login.loginMethod();

        driver.get("https://google.com.uy");
```

However, I'm getting an error saying "driver cannot be resolved". I want to reuse the driver in the loginMethod from "Login.java", I don't want to open a Chrome window (I'd have to log in again).

Is there anything I'm missing? Is it possible to do that?

Comment: You could have the `loginMethod()` return the driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `driver` `public static` and extend `Login` in `AddCompanyTeam` class. Hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

While Pratik's answer does work, you can leverage object oriented programming better by passing a WebDriver object into the constructor instead of using it as a static class:

```
public class AddCompanyTeam {
    private WebDriver driver;

    public <IWebDriver> void main(String[] args) {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        Login login = new Login(driver);

        login.loginMethod();
```

And the Login class becomes:

```
public class Login {
    private WebDriver driver;

    public Login(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public HomePage loginMethod() {
        driver.findElement(...);
        // code to log user in

        return new HomePage(driver);
    }
}
```

The loginMethod could return a HomePage object that represents the home page of your web site, giving you the next page object in the work flow. This pattern, where a method on a page object returns another page object that represents the page you are transitioning to, is a very flexible and robust way to structure your test code.